# Replacing a 5v to 3.3v converter

Tags: power-supply, power, resistors, voltage-regulator

I am currently following [this guide](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-add-airplay-to-your-car-for-high-quality-wirele-512312902) for modding an Airport Express for automotive use. It recommends using a AMS1117-3.3 regulator along with a USB power adapter to power the Airport Express.

I was wondering if  [this device](http://au.element14.com/linear-technology/lt1585act-3-3-pbf/v-reg-3-3v-5a-0-05-3to220/dp/2252745)  is a suitable replacement for the AMS1117-3.3 and if it will do the exact same thing.

EDIT: I have changed the device i'm trying to replace the AMS1117-3.3 for.

Comment: This is a shopping question. Not really in the bent of that this site tries to cater to.

Comment: No, it will not do the same thing.  A 50mA linear regulator will not do the same thing as the 800mA  switch-mode buck converter.  [Meanwhile.  The title of the eBay auction says it's a buck.  But I can't seem to find the inductor on the photos.]

Comment: @NickAlexeev: It's a not a buck, just a linear.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Perhaps, it is linear.  Then that little PCB has to dissipate as much as 1.36W under full load.  Heatsink?  Fan?

Comment: @NickAlexeev: I'm thinking reduced life expectancy instead.

Comment: It seems nobody else has asked: ***why*** do you want a substitute for the AMS1117-3.3 LDO? Those parts are available for as little as [$1.14 for 10 pieces](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10Pcs-AMS1117-3-3-LM1117-3-3V-1A-SOT-223-Voltage-Regulator-/130750978645?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1e715d9a55) with free shipping. What benefit are you looking for, from an alternative?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh: That would be my fault. Part of the question before the edit explained that the asker didn't want to wait for it to be shipped, and therefore was looking for a local alternative.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Hmm, I wonder where "local" is. The LM1117-3.3 (pretty much the same as the AMS1117-3.3) is ubiquitous enough that I can buy them off the shelf at the electronics parts street shops in Mumbai, India, for around $0.20 each.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh: Based on the second links, Australia.

Comment: Not shopping, part/component selections. Should not have been closed.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd Generation (2012) Airport Express uses just a 3.3v internal Supply. Unlike the 1st generation, it uses an on-board boost/step-up converter to power the USB port at the typical 500~700mA.

It comes with a Delta branded 120v AC to 3.3v 2.09 Amp power supply. Of course, not all of this is used, and the most draw will come in when all the features are used (Both ethernet ports, optical out, usb power, etc).

Unfortunately, noone has bothered to hook up an ammeter to measure what the typical or max current from the supply is.

The one recommended in the article is a 800mA max Linear Regulator. You will need a usb supply that can produce atleast 700~800mA 5v, and then a linear regulator to step down 5v to 3.3v atleast 800mA. Most 3.3v linear regulators can do this, even the ones at radioshack. Look for a 1Amp one. Make sure it has a heatsink at the very least.

**Or do the smarter thing and go for a 1 to 2 Amp 12v to 3.3v regulator. You will end up paying the same.** A switching regulator has little heat issues to worry about.

**KEEP IN MIND that that 800mA they used, was only for wifi and 3.5mm out. Do not plug in a usb device or ethernet device, or you might have issues, including a dead Airport Express.**

Answer (score -1):

The AX [uses about 3-4W](http://uk.hardware.info/reviews/3190/11/apple-airport-express-review-new-generation-test-results-energy-consumption). The LM2936-3.3 can supply 3V3 * 50mA = 165mW. The LM2936-3.3 cannot supply enough current, however the AMS1117-3.3 at 3V3 * 1A = **3.3W** is marginally capable *if run outside of spec*.

I recommend you find a *switching* buck converter capable of supplying at least 4W / 3.3V ~= 1.22A instead. As a bonus, it will run off the car's 12V supply and you won't need the lighter-to-USB adapter.

**EDIT:**

Your new part will work, but it will be dissipating about 1.7V * 1.2A ~= 2W of power as heat, so you may want to add a small heatsink to your order.

Comment: I'm actually using an airport express for this (don't know if it makes a difference). The first ebay link is the one many people are using online and it's works for them. Is this not the right one?

Comment: @user2288946: What the... I thought I put "express" into the search box. Stupid Google. Fixing...

Comment: Is the updated product the correct one? It's the "this device" link in the question

Comment: @user2288946: The LT1585ACT-3.3? It's still a linear regulator, so everything it regulates out it has to burn off as heat.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Just as an aside: Two posts down from the one you linked is another post reporting 2.7 Watts for the Airport Express under normal operating load. The 3-4 Watt post is a bit suspect.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh: Link updated to something a bit more rigorous.